# MVVMCross Android: value with binding not updated

Tags: c#, android, binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

I created simple app with Xamarin(Android)+Mvvmcross. I have property Data( type MyData) in my ViewModel.

This is my VievModel

```
public class MyViewModel:MvxViewModel
{
    private MyData _data;
    public MyData Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set
        {
            _data = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Data);
        }
    }
    ....
}

public class MyData: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Current
    {
        get { return _current; }
        set
        {
            _current = value;
            Debug.WriteLine(_current);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Current");
        }
    }
    private string _current;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I use this binding in view

```
 xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

<TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 local:MvxBind="Text Data.Current"
 android:id="@+id/textView" />
```

This is my Timer:

```
 private Timer _timer;
 .....
 public void InitEvent(Action action)
 {
     _timer.Elapsed += TimerTick;
     _action = action;
 }

 private void TimerTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (_action != null)
            _action(); 
 }
```

In _action updated proprrty Current.

When value property is updated Text in TextView does not changed. What is the problem? 
  The value is changed on the timer. Debug.WriteLine(_current) - shows new value. TextView.Text - old value, not updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your "timer" running on a background thread?

If it is, then you'll need to find some way to signal the `RaisePropertyChanged` on the UI thread.

One easy way to do this is to inherit from `MvxNotifyPropertyChanged` - it will automatically marshal the notification on to the UI.

Another is to use `IMvxMainThreadDispatcher` - e.g.

```
public string Current
{
    get { return _current; }
    set
    {
        _current = value;
        Debug.WriteLine(_current);
        Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMainThreadDispatcher>()
           .RequestMainThreadAction(() => NotifyPropertyChanged("Current"));
    }
}
```

Of course, if multiple threads are accessing `set Current` then you may also hit weird threading bugs...

Comment: I didn't change my answer